# What is a quick way to duplicate a tab in macOS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, shortcut

Is there a quick way or shortcut to duplicate a tab in macOS Safari?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Safari 13.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpagQm.jpg) finally added Duplicate Tab functionality, in both the contextual menu on tabs (control select) and in the Window > Duplicate Tab menu.

[image: macOS Safari tab contextual meny]

It doesn't come with a keyboard shortcut by default, but you can [create your own keyboard shortcut in Keyboard preferences](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/mac). (Internet Explorer, where this feature seems to have originated, used <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.)

Comment: Nice! Looks like it duplicates navigation history as well.

Comment: Just for simplicity's sake, to create the shortcut you can follow these instructions:
`System Preferences...` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` tab > `App Shortcuts` > `+` > 
`Application: Safari`
`Menu Title: Duplicate Tab`
`Keyboard Shortcut: ⌘ + K` (or introduce the shortcut you want to use)

Comment: My 2cts: On Safari 15.0, the command should be 'Window->Duplicate Tab'.
Note it uses "->" instead of ">". Wouldn't work for me without.

Answer (score 64):

I have two alternatives:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (go the Location/Search field), then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. Click the back button (`<`), then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while clicking the forward button (`>`).

Both of these will open a tab in the background. (Often, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + *click* opens the click target's reference in a new tab.)

If you also press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while performing the second step of either of these alternatives, the tab will open in the foreground.

Comment: Cmd/L, Cmd/Return, for me. You don't even need to let go of Cmd.

Comment: Would draging the favicon to the tab bar work?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel In El Capitan, getting at the favicon is not easy. First you have to click the location field, then you have to aim for the favicon, and then drag it to the tab placeholder marked `+`, which is also small and difficult to aim for. It works, but it is not a "quick way".

Comment: How is it possible to be that cumbersome to do the basic stuff: a drag-and-drop? But you didnt specify it is on El Capitan. You said "Safari", nothing else.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel For a keyboard oriented person, a shortcut is often faster because the fingers don't have to be moved to the pointing device and one can rely on muscle memory instead of aiming. When the targets are small, drag and drop becomes more cumbersome. (The question relates to Safari in general, but my comment relates to Safari El Capitan, which is the only release I can test.)

Comment: You have a very good point there. It becomes even harder when the target is 32x32 on a Retina screen (which has 2x the DPI of a regular screen, i think). But, for a not-so-tech-savyy person, the drag-and-drop **MAY** be a **bit** easier (on another operating system as well). But physical impaired people will also find your method easier, depending on the physical abilities of the person. But would `F6 + (hold CMD) + C + T + V + (release CMD) + Enter/Return` be easier?

Comment: Works in Chrome too.

Comment: This seems to have the downside that it doesn't try to preserve things like location on the page the way that built-in "duplicate tab" functionality does.

Comment: @mtraceur True. "Duplicate tab" wasn't available when I wrote this. I've instead accepted the answer that suggests you use the new feature.

Comment: @mtraceur — Though that could also be a very minor upside, depending on what you're planning to do with the new tab.

Answer (score 14):

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**How it works**: The first step "Highlights the URL." (File > Open Location...). The second step "Opens the URL in a new background tab."

I'm usually a Chrome user, but I just tested it. It works on Safari, too. I can't find a reference for Safari, but [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) is that for Chrome. (under Mac > Address bar shortcuts)

**Edit**: [Trauts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217563/130792) beat me to it while I was formatting the key glyph. Feel free to ignore my answer and upvote him!

Comment: It does not require 2 separate steps, just simple press literally ⌘+L+Enter (⌘+L+Return) in one action and it duplicates the Tab.

Comment: @user3439894 That's still invoking two separate commands even if you don't lift the ⌘ key between them.

Comment: @devios1, The issue is not the number of commands. The answer states two steps, ⌘L and then ⌘Enter but you do not need to do it in two steps, simple simultaneous press  ⌘+L+Enter in that order without letting up any key until having pressed all threes keys in order. That's one step!

Comment: @user3439894 It’s improper to do that though. The L and Enter keys are not part of the same command. You should release the L before hitting Enter. Keeping command held down is fine as it’s just a modifier. Even if it technically works, it is not good advice the other way as the system is not treating it as a single command.

Comment: @devios1, RE: "It’s improper to do that though"... Who are you, the keyboard police?  When Steve Jobs comes back from the grave and tells me to no longer Think Different, I'll still continue to do what works regardless!

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (go the Location/Search field), then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to open the same page in a new tab.

Comment: How does ⌘⇧Return differ from ⌘Return?

Comment: It opens in a new foreground tab. ⌘Return opens in a background tab.

Answer (score 4):

Hold `cmd` then press `L`, after that `C`, after that `T`, after that `V` and finally release `cmd` and press `enter`. Usually use this so i'm an expert in this and can do this under a milisec. :D Or you make an automator workflow with this.

Comment: Oh Chrome, how I love the fact I can just right click on a tab and select "Duplicate".

Comment: @Gabi - take a look at the top answer...  will save yourself a few unnecessary keystrokes there :)

Comment: @Charlie74 yes, there are some unnecessary steps but usually I'm too lazy to use the mouse :)

Answer (score 4):

Run the following AppleScript via FastScripts, Keyboard Maestro, or other AppleScript-runner utility.

```
# Duplicate Safari Tab next to itself.
set js to "
var docURL = document.URL;
var open_link = window.open('','_blank');
open_link.location=docURL;
"
tell application "Safari"
  tell front document
    do JavaScript js
  end tell
end tell
```

Or place this JavaScript in a bookmark on the Favorites Bar and access via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd>[0-9] or mouse-click.

```
javascript:var%20docURL%20=%20document.URL;var%20open_link%20=%20window.open('','_blank');open_link.location=docURL;
```

Comment: I like the bookmarklet and the hotkey tip.

Answer (score 4):

If you use this a lot i sugest that you change your Safari Settings under "General" you can set "New Tabs open with:" there you select "Same Page"

Now you can just use Cmd-t for open tab an it opens op the same page.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that **Tetsujin** has the best answer (see above).

I read the above tips and tried several. Not noticing his tip at first I accidentally found the same solution, but for it to work this way you must have Safari's preferences set appropriately.

I am using El Capitan, OS X 10.11.1 and Safari 9.01. This tip works because we previously 1) opened Safari's Preferences dialog **(Cmd/Comma)**, 2) selected the ***Tabs*** tab, 3) **set** the ***"Open pages in tabs instead of windows"*** drop-down list box to **Automatically** and 4) **enabled** the **three check boxes** just below that. What this does is mostly self-explanatory - text in the dialog box tells what each choice means.

**Cmd/L, Cmd/Return** - **that's the entire tip!**.  Simple isn't it?

**Cmd/L** means *Open Location* and has the effect of opening the current  URL in Safari's Smart Search field and selects it.

**Cmd/Return** means *Open a page in a new tab*. The URL in the Smart Search field opens in a new tab.

You can type this as 1) press
**Cmd** and hold it while 2) you press **L** then 3) release **L** and press **Return**. You then 4) release both the **Cmd** and **Return** keys and you are done.

These two sets of keypresses will create a duplicate of the tab you are on and make it active.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use several key inputs there's a plugin for just duplication. I can't recall the name of it just now but I have used it before.

**Edit:** Found a plugin that does what you're looking for, it's not the one I have personally used for a long time but still does what you want. Pugin: http://thiemo.ch/safari/

Answer (score 1):

`cmd` + `[` to go back one page, then hold `cmd` and **click the forward arrow** to open a new tab of the page you were just on.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tab Duplicator](https://langui.sh/2010/06/14/tab-duplicator-a-safari-5-extension/) extension does the job, adding both the toolbar menu and an item in current page's context menu.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite simple way of doing that now.

Simply Control + click on the tab you want to duplicate and choose "Duplicate Tab".

[image]

Comment: nice visual - I've made this an edit to the selected answer

Comment: you need to have multiple tabs open or there is no tab for you to right click on to get that command, so looking for a way to duplicate tab when you only have one tab open

Comment: ooh, i found a way to have a tab with only one site open.  under settings -> tabs -> tab layout: switch from separate to compact

Comment: @luckyguy73 Yep. ;)